# Can I use a provider for all my render functions in react testing library?

Tags: react-testing-library

Is there a way to wrap in a provider all my renders? I have a theme provider and now I have to wrap all my test renders with it, like this:

```js
render(<SameProviderInAllMyTest value={theme}>
  <TheComponentImTesting>
 <SameProviderInAllMyTest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom render for this . The testing library documentation has an example for this on how to setup a custom render .

[Custom Render Setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render)